# Using a member access lambda expression to parametrise a LINQ to SQL predicate

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a query that needs to be reused all over the place and I need to vary which property/column gets used for a join.

What I'd like to be able to do is something like:

```
query = RestrictByProp(query, x=>x.ID);
```

An extremely simplified `RestrictByProp()` could  be*:

```
private static IQueryable<Role> RestrictByProp(IQueryable<Role> query, 
                                               Func<Role, int> selector)
{
    return query.Where(x => selector(x) == 1);
}
```

The problem is that even this simple implementation causes a runtime exception:

```
Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no 
supported translation to SQL.
```

**(Here I'm just adding a simple 'where' clause - in my real code I'd be using the lambda to pick which property to use for a join).*

I find this strange because if the member access lambda is done inline it is fine:

```
 private static IQueryable<Role> RestrictByID(IQueryable<Role> query)
 {
     return query.Where(x=> x.ID == 1);
 }
```

LINQ to SQL is also happy if you pass in an `Expression<Func<Role, bool>>` (i.e. when the parameter is `x=>x.ID == 1`) but that defeats the object because I need the value of the right-hand operand to be determined within the query.

**Is there a way to somehow munge the lambda expression in `RestrictByProp()` so that LINQ to SQL knows how to generate the SQL?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to change your method signature:

```
private static IQueryable<Role> RestrictByProp(IQueryable<Role> query, 
    Expression<Func<Role, int>> selector)
```

That will mean your lambda expression is converted into an expression tree instead of a delegate.

You'll then need to build an `Expression<Func<Role, bool>>` from the existing expression tree.

It will look *something* like this:

```
LambdaExpression lambda = (LambdaExpression) selector;
var predicate = Expression.Equal(selector, Expression.Constant(1));
var lambdaPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Role, bool>>(predicate,
                                                          lambda.Parameters);
return query.Where(lambdaPredicate);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to apply that to my beast of a query now. I suppose I'll have to build up a massive expression tree. Or is this where ExpressionVisitor comes in handy?

For anyone else who needs to use this code, I needed to change something to make it work (and I can't edit :):

    1) Expression.Equal(lambda*.Body* ... and 2) Expression.Lambda<Func<Role, *bool*>>

Comment: @stucampbell: Thanks, I've fixed the typos. Not sure about `ExpressionVisitor` - I haven't used it myself yet.

Comment: Hi Jon, can you go deeper with explanations about this solution? Thank you

Comment: @Tobia: Not without specific details about what's needed. Maybe you should ask a new questions with details about what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried, and what went wrong.